# CodeClimate CamelCase issue

Tags: php, camelcasing, code-climate

I recently tried codeclimate. In the style codeclimate report an error on a parameter that is not camel notation.
the function is written like this:

```
function asd ($_par) {}
```

I am aware that it is in the form:

```
function asd ($parameterInCamel) {}
```

but, it is not even in this form:

```
function asd ($parameter_in_und) {}
```

I usually use in function parameters underscore as the first char to identify them from other variables.
It can be considered a stylistic error?

Answer (score 0):

click "disable check" button at each issue in the codeclimate's issue page, then you will see how to ignore issue.

firstable, you need to set .codeclimate.yml to your project.